# How to use fallbackDetails in SPFx react

Tags: typescript-typings, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using @microsoft/mgt-react": "^2.1.0" and I see "fallbackDetails" in the documentation but no exammple how to use it.

I tried:

```
    return (<td title={uName} >
     <Person personQuery={email} showPresence={true} view={PersonViewType.oneline} 
      **fallbackDetails={fallback } //Here Tslint Error**
      personCardInteraction={PersonCardInteraction.hover} />
      </td>
    );
```

The complin is:

```
fallbackDetails: IDynamicPerson; personCardInteraction: PersonCardInteraction.hover; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PersonProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'fallbackDetails' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PersonProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

Can anyone provide an example that TypeScript will accept?
Or maybe there is a Types.d.ts that I need to get

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got a message from mgt.
the format should be:
fallbackDetails={{"displayName":"test displayName" , mail:"someone@contoso.com"}}

The complain was because I had the second prperty as email:"someone@contoso.com"

All is good now.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I'd recheck any other mgt-* packages to make sure they're upgraded as well, and the fallback object you are feeding it.

The most basic react sample would look like the following:

```
        <Person
          personQuery={'me'}
          fallbackDetails={{"displayName":"test displayName"}}
          line2clicked={() => console.log('line1 clicked')}
          line1Property="displayName"
          line2Property="mail"
          view={PersonViewType.twolines}
        />
```